# render php file from note.js for jquery

Tags: php, node.js, express

I'm trying to take user input data from a webpage and adding to an SQL database. The approach I'm taking (there might be a simpler way but I'm not sure what that would be) is to take the data from the HTML page using Javascript using `document.getElementById(xxx).value;` and using jQuery.ajax to sent it to a .php file that will be sent to the database.

The I'm having is in the link between the jQuery and the .php file. Since my whole website is being hosted on node.js using express I rendered the .php to http://localhost:5000/test.php using php-node but that not working giving me the following error

```
Error: Command failed: C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\Users\...\Part1\views\test.php

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:297:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1001:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:266:5)
```

is there a way to get over that issue since I can't find one or if there is was to approach it in a completely different way I'm more than happy to try it?

I'm not really sure what is causing it.

Thanks in advance.

---

here is all the relevant code:

I am aware that the test.php isn't sending anything to the database I just set up like that for "figuring out where is the issue" purposes.

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const mysql = require("mysql");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const path = require("path");
var phpnode = require('php-node')({bin:"C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"});

dotenv.config({
    path: './mySQL.env'
});

const app = express();

let db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
});

app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.engine('php', phpnode);
app.set('view engine', 'php');

const publicDirectory = path.join(__dirname, './public');
app.use(express.static(publicDirectory));

app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.use(express.json());

db.connect((error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

    else {
        console.log("SQL connected")

        db.query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS TMA2_P1", (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }

            else {
                console.log("DATABASE Created")
            }
        });
    }
});

db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE
});

db.connect((error) =>{
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

    else {
        db.query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(50), password VARCHAR(16), primary key (id))", (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }

            else {
                console.log("users Table Creates")
            }
        });
    }
});

app.use('/', require('./routes/pages.js'));

app.use('/auth', require('./routes/auth.js'));

app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Node server listening on port 5000!');
});
```

**routes/pages.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/login', ((req, res) => {
    res.render('login.hbs')
}));

router.get('/register', ((req, res) => {
    res.render('register.hbs')
}));

router.get('/bookmark', ((req, res) => {
    res.render('bookmark-main.hbs')
}));

router.get('/bookmark/:userId', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params)
    if (req.session.loggedinUser) {
        res.render('bookmark-login.hbs', {
            name: req.session.name
        })
    }

    else {
        res.redirect('login.hbs')
    }

});

router.get('/logout', ((req, res) => {
    req.session.loggedinUser = false;
    res.redirect('/bookmark');
}));

router.get('/test.php', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('test.php');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

$data = array();

$data['siteName'] = $_POST['siteName'];
$data['URL'] = $_POST['URL'];
$data['user'] = $_POST['user'];

echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

**bookmark-login.hbs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Your Bookmarks</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/Bookmark.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <a href="#">TMA2</a>
        <a href="/Bookmark">Bookmark</a>
        <a href="/logout">
            <button class="button-logout">Logout</button>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="header">
        <h1>{{name}}'s Bookmarks</h1>
        <input id="username" style="display: none" value="{{name}}">
    </div>

    <div class="main-center">
        <h2>Add Bookmark</h2>
        <form class="form-content">
            <div>
                <input name="site_name" id="site_name" type="text" placeholder="Site Name">
            </div>

            <br>

            <div>
                <input name="url" id="url" type="text" placeholder="https://www.example.com">
            </div>

            <br>

            <button class="save_button" id="sub_button">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="bookmarks"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Bookmark.js**

```
const SiteName = document.getElementById('site_name').value;
const URL = document.getElementById('url').value;
const user = document.getElementById('username').value;
const button = document.getElementById('sub_button')


button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/test.php',
        data: {
            siteName: SiteName,
            URL: URL,
            user: user,
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(status)
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Why are you using PHP at all?

Comment: @Dai not really by choice tbh the assignment said use PHP, but at this point, I am willing to pretend I never read that part. I still can't find a way to have the javascript file pull the data from the webpage and access SQL but I could be overlooking something